# OR WHERE IN in laravel Query Builder with sub query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

How can make query builder for following Query

```
SELECT * FROM `rad_nas` WHERE nas_assigned = ".$id." 
OR nas_assigned IN 
(select franchise_id from rad_franchise_has_parent where parent_id=".$id." )
OR nas_id IN 
(select  fra_nas_id  from rad_franchise_has_nas where franchise_nas_id=".$id.")
```

Comment: See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

Answer (score 2):

Check the docs for future uses and don't post a question and expect other people to write or debug your code for you, that is your job, we are giving you guidance, but here is a complete example when you transform that to `Query Builder`

```
$results = DB::table('rad_nas')->where('nas_assigned', $id)
             ->orWhereIn('nas_assigned', function($query) use ($id) {
                  $query->select('franchise_id')
                        ->from('rad_franchise_has_parent')
                        ->where('parent_id', $id);
             }
             ->orWhereIn('nas_id', function($query) use ($id) {
                  $query->select('fra_nas_id')
                        ->from('rad_franchise_has_nas')
                        ->where('franchise_nas_id', $id);
             }
```

As @DanielO pointed out

> Raw statements will be injected into the query as strings, so you should be extremely careful to not create SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Isn't this a potential SQL injection vulnerability? `parent_id=".$id`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @DanielO, but I wrote a quick example so he can get a general idea of how to, but Ive made a complete example now without `DB::raw` @YuvarajJeganathan

Comment: Thanks @NikolaGavric sorry for my code and i didn't find **orwhereIn** in documnent